# socket call fails with error code 0

Tags: windows, sockets

Running the following code on a win8 system

```
memset(&sin,0,sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = PORTNUM;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1));

if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
  printf("Could not obtain server socket (rc=%d): %s\n",
          errno,strerror(errno));
  return 0;
}
```

results in s being set to -1 but errno being set to 0.  Can anyone suggest what could cause this?

Comment: What is the value of PORTNUM? What is the full output (printf)?

Comment: I changed the code to

   sin.sin_port = htons(2044);

running this produces

  Could not obtain server socket (rc=0): No error

Comment: I think that for type SOCK_STREAM, protocol cannot be 0

Comment: I tried using IPPROTO_TCP instead with the same results.

Comment: It's strange, have you called the `WSAStartup()` function?

Comment: I don't know what that is (I'm mostly a Unix programmer).

Comment: OK, I looked it up and calling WSAStartup() did allow the socket call to succeed.  However, I'm now having the same problem with the call to connect; i.e. the call fails with a 0 error code.  Here's the entire code segment

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int  Reuse_PORT = 1;
  WORD wVersionRequested;
  WSADATA wsaData;
  wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
  WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
  int s;
  struct sockaddr_in sin;
  struct hostent *hp;
  memset(&sin,0,sizeof(sin));
  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
  setsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char  *)&Reuse_PORT,sizeof(Reuse_PORT));

  connect(s,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin));

Comment: Please, can you edit the question and put that code in there? So that everyone can see it without the need of copy and paste.